# Shear Stress and Moment about leading edge

Tags: aerodynamics

Does the shear stress contribute to the moment about the leading edge?
And if it does, how can we calculate the moment about the leading edge provided that the shear stress is dependant on the surface.

Comment: I don't think that the question is very clear. What shear stress? Direction? Orientation? And what leading edge?

Comment: You need to draw a diagram for us showing what you are asking.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might be asking whether an airfoil's skin friction contributes to the foil's pitching moment. Is that correct?

Comment: Boundary layer shear stress is VERY non-linear and depends on speed and size. The only real option you have is to integrate it numerically. The airfoil coordinates will make it easy to calculate the lever arm: They start with zero at the leading edge.